# How do I know what packages I need to install?

Tags: apt

Not for any specific program, just in general if I wanted to install something via APT how do I know what packages I need to "apt-get install" for that program

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$ apt-cache search <mysearchterm> <othersearchterm>
```

to search for packages matching these terms in the description field. For example, let's say you're looking for a PDF viewer for use in KDE, you could do this:

```
$ apt-cache search pdf viewer kde
okular - universal document viewer
```

Then use `apt-cache show <pkgname>` to show more details:

```
Description-en: universal document viewer
 Okular is a universal document viewer with support for advanced document
 features, such as annotations, forms, and embedded files.
 .
 This package provides the document viewer application, plus plugins for a wide
 variety of document formats such as:
  * PostScript (PS)
  * Portable Document Format (PDF)
[...]
```

Alternatively, use any other package management tool that you like. E.g.:

- [aptitude [image: Install aptitude]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptitude) (ncurses-based semi-GUI in terminal)
- [synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic) (GUI)

They all provide similar search functionality which is more user friendly than `apt-cache search`.

Comment: So the apt-cache search command will work for example if I downloaded skype I have the file itself that I want to manually install I could just go to the terminal and type "apt-cache search skype" in the terminal and it would show me a list of packages which fall under skype then I would apt-get install each of them?  Im very new at linux sorry.

Comment: @user200923 You don't need to provide all the packages as an argument to `apt-get install`, it will find the dependencies by itself. Just have a try! And no, it won't work for software downloaded from random websites - APT works with software repositories. If you need Skype, enable the Canonical Partner repository, it includes Skype in there. Then APT will know about it.

Comment: So as far as downloading random software how would I know what to install, obviously I could look for a tutorial but there is a way I assume to download a random software program and find its packages that need to be installed then go ahead and install them.

Comment: APT downloads packages for you! Please **don't** go to a website to look for or download software. Ubuntu works with **repositories** instead. Just ask your package management what package provides the functionality like I demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Maybe Skype was the wrong program to say. I understand I shouldn't go and download some random software, but I understand how to fix computers (Im a computer technician) even if I do mess something up. So, now say I was to actually go and download some random software off of some random website, well call it "ubsoft" from ubsoft.com. I download this file and I want to install it. there is no specific repository for this file. How would you download it once you had the file? As I said Im new to ubuntu so Im very sorry for being frustrating or ignorant

Comment: @user200923 Please ask a **new** question. This is very much out of scope from your initial question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I just posted a question, hopefully it is a little more clear.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/359090/how-would-i-download-a-random-program-for-a-random-website