# How would I install a random program from a random website?

Tags: installation, apt

So I will just give an example and hopefully your response can clear it up for me. I need some random piece of software. For lack of creativity, I will call this program "ubsoft". I'm downloading this program from some random site called "ubsoft.com". Now please put me into your shoes. If you just downloaded this file, how would you install it if you can't do it via `apt-get` because the proper repository doesn't exist?

Comment: What is the file extension of the downloaded file?

Comment: @minerz029 It's [arbitrary](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/909/). If it affects your answer, explain how.

Comment: If it is a .tar.gz, you would generally just unpack it and run. If it is a .deb you would open it in the software center. If it is a .run or .sh you would run it in a terminal. It is completely different for different file types

Comment: @ændrük If it's *arbitrary*, then question is *unclear* because as DaboRoss said, there are completely different installation methods.

Comment: @minerz029 My interpretation of the question is that it's deliberately nonspecific—a clear question about the general case. I consider DaboRoss's comment to be an accurate (albeit terse and misplaced) answer.

Comment: @DaboRoss Can you put that into an answer?

Comment: @minerz029 I will soon, It just isn't that flushed out right now :P

Comment: @ændrük the problem is that is too broad, and there are several approaches that we won't end up. OP needs to say what specific case he's referring to. The method to install a RPM, DEB, EXE, sources, RUN, etc. are too wide and there are already questions and answers for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default way to install software on Linux is using the package manager, which in the case of Ubuntu is apt-get or the software centre. Otherwise you can compile the package from source.

To be fair, you should ask ubsoft.com if they are not using the package method. The method will differ from package to package. For example, some may require running an install script/program, while others may just require uncompress of an archive.

Therefore, my response is 'it depends.'